# What does "declare +x" mean vs "declare -x"?

Tags: bash, shell

What does `declare +x` do below? (Specific to Bash.) I understand `declare -x`, but not `declare +x`:

```
function the_func {
  declare +x MY_VAR="new value"
  child-process
}

export MY_VAR="original"
the_func
```

Comment: Take a look at command: `help declare`

Answer (score 2):

With

```
declare -x MY_VAR="new value"
```

you **export** variable **MY_VAR** into the environment, whereas with

```
declare +x MY_VAR="new value"
```

you **remove** that variable from the environment.

Generally speaking, for the **declare** command, using **+** undoes the action done by **-**.

More info can be found [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare)

Comment: `declare -x` is not same as `export`, if you call it inside fuction declare -x will export it only within scope of function, where export do export into environment OS